# Applying a function to a directory

Tags: r, loops, matrix, directory, lapply

I have a function that takes three matrix data files (LAT, LON, DATA) and combines them into one csv file with three columns. However, this is for one day in my time series of daily data from 2010-2015, so I need to apply this to a directory of data files. The LAT and LON files will not vary, just the DATA files by date. My question is simply: how do I apply this function to my directory so it provides me with a new CSV file with the date in the name of the new csv file. Thoughts? I've tried a few things, with no luck. Here is my code:

```
    ####PR PRAG WATER DATA XYZ###
setwd("/Users/andrewbudsock/Dropbox/Research/ActualET_PR")
LON<-read.csv("LONGITUDE.csv")
LAT<-read.csv("LATITUDE.csv")
ET<-read.csv("actual_ET20100101.csv")
###STACKOVERFLOW TRY######
myList<-list(LON=LON, LAT=LAT, ET = ET)
  lapply(myList, function(x){
    as.matrix(x) %>%
      as.numeric()
  }) %>%
  as.data.frame()
Flat<-na.omit(flattened)
write.csv("flat.csv", Flat)

DataName<-seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = 'day')
as.list(DataName)
write.csv(Flat, "xyz.csv");

#loop all files in 
files <- list.files(path="/Users/andrewbudsock/Dropbox/Research/ActualET_PR", pattern="*.csv", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
lapply(files, function(x) {
  t <- read.table(x, header=T) # load file
  # apply function
  out <- function(t){
    for(i in length(t)){
      myList= list(LAT=LAT, LON=LON, ET=t[i])
      lapply(myList, function(x){
        as.matrix(x) %>%
          as.numeric()
      }) %>%
        as.data.frame()
      Flat<-na.omit(flattened)
    }
  }
    # write to files
    write.table(out, "/Users/andrewbudsock/Dropbox/Research/ActualET_PR/R", paste(DataName, ".csv", sep = ""), sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=F, col.names=T)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the files need to be written separately? Said another way, would it be as good (better even?) to have one file with all of your data in it? If so, and assuming the file names above are accurate, you can get the store all the file names with this (note, I am explicitly grabbing lat/lon first so they are the first columns). Using `dplyr`

```
myfiles <-
  c(
    # LAT/LONG files
    list.files(pattern = "*TUDE.csv")
    # Data files
    , list.files(pattern = "^actual_ET")
    ) %>%
  # Set names by removing csv or the leading portion
  setNames(gsub("\\.csv|actual_ET", "", .))
```

Then, you can read all of the values into a list with:

```
myList <-
  lapply(myfiles, read.csv)
```

Then, just pass the whole list to the `lapply` call from your previous question:

```
out <-
  lapply(myList, function(x){
    as.matrix(x) %>%
      as.numeric()
  }) %>%
  as.data.frame()
```

And you will get one data.frame with everything in it.

If, instead, you really need a separate file for each date, you should be able to read in the data as above, then use the code below. This skips the first two entries of `myList` (your lat/lon), and generates a new file for each date, using the names set above to name the output file. I also have it saving the resulting file into the variable `sepOuts` though that is not strictly necessary.

```
sepOuts <-
  lapply(seq(3, length(myList), 1), function(idx){

    out <-
      lapply(myList[c(1,2,idx)], function(x){
        as.matrix(x) %>%
          as.numeric()
      }) %>%
      as.data.frame()

    write.csv(out, paste0("fileNameLeader_"
                          , names(myList)[idx]
                          , "_anyTrailingName.csv"))

    return(out)
  }) %>%
  setNames(names(myList)[-c(1,2)])
```

Comment: Hey Thanks mark! One last issue with this. for some reason:

Comment: list.files(pattern = "actual_ET*.csv") is returning zero values. files names are structured like this actual_ET20151224.csv, and change by date. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry about that, with out files to check against, I forgot about some of the oddities of the `list.files` pattern matching. It does not handle `*` for a reason that I do not remember. Instead, try `list.files(pattern = "^actual_ET")` to match anything that starts with "actual_ET". Will edit in the answer

Comment: It does handle `*` since it uses regex. In regex `*` means "match the previous character zero or more times". `.` means any character. So the regex should look something like `"actual_ET\\d*\\.csv$"`.

Comment: Thank you @Roland -- you are (of course) correct. I had mistakenly confused regex and command-line wildcard expansion, and make this mistake more often than I care to admit when using `list.files`. This reminder should help me, and hopefully the OP.